# Adding stuffs to PATH in Linux

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

I have recently started off with Linux, and am having some confusion with how to set something to PATH, I went through many wikis, but things aren't getting cleared, like I wanted to know what is the difference between putting things into the .bashrc file and /etc/environment file, and do we put the directory paths into the .bashrc file only, or is there some other file which we can use to mention our environment variables?

Comment: The rule of thumb is to avoid setting a long `$PATH`.

Comment: I would amend the above statement: While brevity is a nice thing to have, there is no particular detriment to a large `PATH` (if it's done properly). On all HPC systems I've worked on `PATH` end others will grow to multiple pages of text to accomodate specific software installations. `module` resp. LMOD is the way to go for dynamic settings, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to know what is the difference between putting things into the .bashrc file and /etc/environment file,

Linux is a multi-user system. The same Linux computer (e.g. laptop) can be used by you and by your partner. At 10am you are using it, at 3pm you give your laptop to your partner and he would use it (with a different login). And you can configure your laptop to hide your files to your partner.

Linux workstations can be used by several users (human persons) at once. For example, you can buy a Linux desktop, and plug two screens, two keyboards, two mouses into it, and configure all that to have two different persons using it at once.

The Linux terminology is "seat" (it refers to a human person sitting in front of some Linux screen, and often having some keyboard + mous). See [sd_get_seats](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_get_seats.html#) function.

You could even configure your laptop so that your colleague is accessing your laptop A from his/her laptop B with [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

With that in mind:

- `/etc/environment` is (like every other file under `/etc/`) setting something globally (for users using [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/))
- your `$HOME/.bashrc` (e.g. `/home/peter/.bashrc` if your `$HOME` is `/home/peter`) is specific to you. Your colleague John (accessing the same computer) will use the settings in `/home/john/.bashrc`
- John could have a different login shell (e.g. [zsh](https://zsh.org/)). Then his settings are in `/home/john/.zshrc` and other files.
- Most [supercomputers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer) (costing 10M€ or 10MUS$) are running Linux, and used by hundreds of different persons (sitting in different offices, or even cities) at the same time.

Because of [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques, many Linux distributions are using (internally) other "users" to restrict access to services like databases. See [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).

The `$PATH` is explained in [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and used by functions like [exec(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) (that most Unix shells are calling). A lot of Linux shells are open source (e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [zsh](https://zsh.org)) and you could study their source code (and improve it), or code your own shell. I advise to have a short `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are: `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`

**Assuming** you are using BASH as your shell (default e.g. on CentOS, OpenSUSE, Knoppix and others).

The first two are generally not to be used as they are subject to change on system updates. If you must set global paths and environment (i.e. for *every user*) use `/etc/bashrc.local` or `/etc/profile.local`  .

If you want to set env. variables for yourself/one user only then use `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.
`~/.profile` is read for a login-shell only (according to the comments in mine):

```
# This file is read each time a login shell is started.
# All other interactive shells will only read .bashrc; this is particularly
# important for language settings, see below.
```

So shells you start by clicking on a `Terminal` icon will read `~/.bashrc`.

As a rule I tend to put my global `PATH` modifications (i.e. for CUDA) into `/etc/bashrc.local` and anything that is only for me into `~/.bashrc`.

Modifying `PATH` (and others) should be done by prepending to it via:
`export PATH=<path>/<to>/<new SW binaries>:$PATH` as the `PATH` is parsed from left to right and you likely want your manual installations to supercede any default installation on the system.

Comment: Thankyou, this was quite nicely explained and solves my confusion :)